# How to print an array at the WinMips64?

Tags: printing, mips, mips64

How can I print an array in Mips64? I've succeeded in printing the array in QtSPIM (MIPS32), with this code:

```
.data
array:  .word   10 20 30 40 50

.text
#load base address of array
la $t1,array    
#load number of elements
ld $t2,num

loop:

#load word
lw $a0, ($t1)

#print element
li $v0,1
syscall

#print space
la $a0, space
li $v0,4
syscall

addi $t1,4
#increase counter
addi $t0, 1

bne $t0,$t2,loop


#end
li  $v0,10
syscall
```

I know that MIPS64 has `daddi` instead of `addi` but I am still missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinMips64 doesn't appear to use `syscall` for terminal output like SPIM / MARS, but rather implements it using memory-mapped I/O (see [this example code](http://computing.dcu.ie/~omacfh/ca226/mike_notes/winmips64/testio.s)).

The `CONTROL` port is located at address `0x10000`, and the `DATA` port at address `0x10008`.

Since you're printing integers you'll be interested mainly in these two output modes:

```
; Set CONTROL = 1, Set DATA to Unsigned Integer to be output
; Set CONTROL = 2, Set DATA to Signed Integer to be output
```

For example:

```
ori $a1,$0,0
lui $a1,1       ; $a1 = 0x10000 (CONTROL)
ori $a2,$a1,8   ; $a2 = 0x10008 (DATA)

lwu $a0,($t1)   ; load an unsigned 32-bit value
ori $v0,$0,1    ; 1 == print unsigned integer
sd $a0, ($a2)   ; set value to print        
sd $v0, ($a1)   ; ..and write the command to print it
```

Comment: The lines `la $a1, 0x10000`, `la $a2, 0x10008` and `li $v0,  1` won't compile using winMips64.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: I've fixed that now.